# Empty Popup window in Swift

Tags: swift

Okay, so I'm trying to covert a chunk of code from Objective-C to Swift.

The Objective-C snippet looks like so:

```
[serialListPullDown removeAllItems];
```

Apple shows the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQewA.jpg

So why doesn't say:

```
removeAllItems(serialListPullDown)
```

Work? That seems to be what they are suggesting?

Comment: please read the [language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) before trying to do anything with it

Comment: it should actually be `serialListPullDown.removeAllItems`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Objective-C writing this:**

`[serialListPullDown removeAllItems];`

**Means:** call the method `removeAllItems` on the object `serialListPullDown`.

The syntax to do that in swift is: `<object>.<method>()`, **not** `<method>(<object>)` like you were trying.

**It should be:**

`serialListPullDown.removeAllItems()`